# I created a app using create-react-app but I am not able to launch it by "npm start"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-start

These are the errors:

> npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-04-21T03_3605
>   489Z-debug.log

**The complete log file can be found here:**

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.4
3 info using node@v12.16.2
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle robofriends@0.1.0~prestart: robofriends@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle robofriends@0.1.0~start: robofriends@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle robofriends@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle robofriends@0.1.0~start: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\ADMIN\robofriends\node_modules\.bin;C:\Python38\Scripts\;C:\Python38\;C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\bin;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\;C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\;C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle robofriends@0.1.0~start: CWD: C:\Users\ADMIN\robofriends
10 silly lifecycle robofriends@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'react-scripts start' ]
11 silly lifecycle robofriends@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle robofriends@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: robofriends@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:310:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:310:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
14 verbose pkgid robofriends@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\ADMIN\robofriends
16 verbose Windows_NT 6.3.9600
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v12.16.2
19 verbose npm  v6.14.4
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error robofriends@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the robofriends@0.1.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Also,  I have tried deleting `lock-json` file and then re-installing `npm` but it doesn't help. Please help me fix this issue.

Comment: Could you paste the link of the path of your folder where you are creating your app,

Comment: try to run ```npm cache clean``` or ```npm cache clear``` then do install again

Comment: @ANUPAMCHAUDHARY this is the path :C:\Users\ADMIN

Comment: @MuhammadAdamC I tried doing that. As nothing worked I reinstalled Nodejs from scratch and now I am getting different set of error messages as follows:

Comment: npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...C9r6bF3N3/4qd0RKKgu
BE'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Pankti Shah\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-22T09_
09_11_744Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts
 cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting my/ from C:\Users\Pankti Shah
Done.

Comment: No I want the complete path to your directory where you are running npm start till there. not just C:\Users\Admin but also the folder where your app is.